# В чем проблема? c#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: ((((]

```
using System;

namespace nakr
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Накрутка голосов бесплатно без смс и регистрации и порно";
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.BufferHeight = 100;
            Console.BufferWidth = 100;
            Console.WriteLine("Напишите Ваш логин:");
            String login = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Ваш логин точно: " + login + "?");
        String t1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (t1.Length = 2)
                Console.WriteLine("ОК");
            else if (t1.Length = 3)
                Console.WriteLine("УХАДИ");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("УХАДИ АРАРАР");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: И в чём же проблема?

Comment: Когда задаёте вопрос, пишите в заголовке в чем именно у вес затруднение. Ну и учитесь читать по-русски, на скриншоте все видно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте текстовое представление кода и сообщений об ошибках. Изображения не очень подходят для этой цели

Comment: == вместо =, это элементарный синтаксис языка - будет написано на первой же странице любого учебника по C#

Answer (score 3):

```
if (t1.Length = 2)
```

оператор сравнения в C# - это двойное равно - `==`

```
if (t1.Length == 2)
```

<sub>без регистрации и sms</sub>

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.
Но сейчас возникла еще одна проблема.
Почему >else нельзя использовать? Скриншот добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @Joctopus потому что в C# надо ставить фигурные скобки. а не просто писать код наугад.